# After converting a categorical variable to dummies, can I use all dummies in my decision tree and random forest?

Tags: regression, logistic, random-forest

When we learn about statistical models, we learn that we shouldn't have dummy variables that are complementary. For instance, if we have only men and women in the dataset, once we have a dummy variable for men, we shouldn't have a dummy variable for women. Is this still something we need to care when using decision tree, random forest or other methods?

And - this is not a statistical question, so don't care about answering if you don't know - should I worry about this when using Python?

Comment: In statistical models the constraint of *k-1* dummies only applies to regression models that include an intercept. In the absence of an intercept, *k* dummies can be used. Obviously, in a decision tree a second dummy for a binary variable would be redundant.

Comment: It's OK to have all levels of a categorical variables for decision tree or random forest model, it won't break anything like it does for linear models, but I would suggest drop it to k-1 levels. Reason being there's randomness in which variables are going to be selected to split the tree and if you have all 2 levels of a binary variables in, it will split the importance and make the interpretation tricky. However I don't know how that will affect the overall performance of the model though, probably don't matter much.